# How can I improve the FPS and decrease the lag I'm getting while using a Raspberry Pi to look for circles?

Tags: python, performance, raspberry-pi, hough-transform

Got a little question:
At the moment I'm working on detecting circles with my raspberry pi with a webcam. 
There are plenty of topics on detecting circles in python with HoughCircles, and I got that working. It's a little bit too slow though: It gives me a huge lag of a couple of seconds.
In these seconds, it keeps printing "no circles detected" even though I am sure I'm keeping my circle in front of the webcam. A couple of seconds later, it prints the location of the center.

My code is pasted below, any help is appreciated!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

camera_port = 0
ramp_frames = 20 #throw away to make it adjust to light levels

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port) #define camera class
retval = camera.set(3,320) #width of frame
retval = camera.set(4,240) #height of frame

def get_image(): #function to get 1 image
 retval, im = camera.read()
 return im

for i in xrange(ramp_frames): #adjust to light levels, throw away 20 frames
 temp = get_image()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    camera_capture = get_image() # Take the actual image we want to keep

    #processing
    img = camera_capture 
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,1,param1=200,param2=80,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
    if circles is not None:
        x=circles[0][0][0]
        y=circles[0][0][1]
        print "x= ",x,"y= ",y
    else:
        print "no circles detected"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the things you want to do, i do know that

```
if circles is not None:
```

is very much unwanted!

see:["Python Boolean Operations"](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#booleans)

try:

```
if circles:
```

I don't think it will fix your problem, but at least your problem will look more pythonic! ;)

Good luck!

Comment: This didn't work, probably because circles is an array if circles are detected and a "NoneType" object if there are no circles detected?

Comment: I guess that would be true... Maybe i should not have answered without knowing anything about the packages you are using. However I still think the statement as is is not very pythonic, as your are repeating yourself: "not None" there must be a neater way. but for now, consider my answer as not posted... :(

Comment: Just a thought... what is the framerate of the camera, and might it be  higher then 20 fps? Because as far as i know, webcams can strugle to find the correct lighting. This may result in longer adjusting times(= more frames). Try raising the number of discarded frames...

Comment: Where are the docs for cv2 located? You got me interested! I've searched arround for a bit but i can't find it, though cv2 seems to be part of the python standardlib?